# How to enable JOB EXECUTOR in jBPM 6?

Tags: workflow, jobs, jbpm, executor

I want to enanble job executor in jBPM 6.
i know org.kie.executor.disabled is the property used to do so.
But how to do it?

Comment: Where do you want to enable it? are you using KIE-Workbench? Or the jBPM Console NG? do you have your own standalone application? In order to get help please be more specific. Regards

Comment: i am using kie-workbench, i found setting under jobs tab. is it for this purpose? what is Frequency and No of threads? is it how much async task thread?